# How can I fix an accidental downvote?

Tags: support, editing, down-votes, best-practices

I recently downvoted a post by accident, but I didn't realize my mistake until some 3o minutes or so later when I noticed the downvote in my reputation log. I meant to upvote the post.

Is there a way to fix this? The system would not allow me to change my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might remember that when you tried to undo the mistake, it showed that you can reverse it only if the post is edited. So you must try to edit the post that you accidentally downvoted. You may be able to find something in that post that could be edited, $e.g.$ tags. If you don't have enough reputation, your edit will be suggested and hopefully accepted. Once the post is edited, you may reverse the downvote and do upvote. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This answer is correct, but please don't make trivial edits *just* to fix a downvote. One accidental downvote is not going to ruin anyone's experience here on the site. If you can't find an obvious way to *improve* the post via an edit, you can click "follow" under the post, and you'll get an inbox notification if the post is edited by someone else.